# Setting a new environment variable with alias

Tags: zsh, alias

Is it possible to create a new environment variable with an alias?

I'm aware that I could set the environment variable as an alias to begin with, but I need it to be dynamic and able to change on the fly.

E.g, I work in Film on different shots at a time, so when I open a program I set the shot through the my environment variable like this:

```
export shot=abc_123
```

What I would like to do is not have to type out 'export shot=' and just type 'shot abc_123' in to a shell which would change the env var.

I am using zsh on osx.

Any ideas on how I can integrate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) function that implements this in our `~/.zshrc` like so:

```sh
function setShot() {
    export shot="$@"
}
```

Then, we can call the function, and all params will be set to the `shot` variable.

Small example:

```sh
$
$ which setShot
setShot () {
    export shot="$@"
}
$
$ echo $shot

$
$ setShot testShot_1234
$
$ echo $shot
testShot_1234
$
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.